# Is {key: {$in: ["Only One Element"]}} equivalent to {key: "Only One Element"}

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is the MongoDB query

```
{key: {$in: ["Only One Element"]}}
```

equivalent to

```
{key: "Only One Element"}
```

in terms of performance?

Comment: Really? Why would it not be? Is it so hard to try?

Answer (score 0):

A wrote a simple test script: https://gist.github.com/nellessen/5f2d36de4ef74b5a34b3

with the following result:

- Average milis for $in with index: 0.12271258831
- Average milis for simple query with index: 0.114794611931
- Average milis for $in without index: 1.51113886833
- Average milis for simple query without index: 1.40885763168

So as a result `{key: {$in: ["Only One Element"]}}` is **7% slower** than `{key: "Only One Element"}`!